# PHP ZipArchive password not working - not accepting set password

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

I am trying to create a password protected zip file using ZipArchive. While the zip file is being encrypted (asking for a password to open the zip) the password I am setting is not working when trying to open the zip.

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
if ($zip->open('test.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE) === TRUE) {
    $zip->setPassword('mypassword'); //set default password

    $zip->addFile('thing1.txt'); //add file
    $zip->setEncryptionName('thing1.txt', ZipArchive::EM_AES_256); //encrypt it

    $zip->close();
}
```

I am using PHP 7.3 and Libzip 1.8.

The zip file generated here does not open when I use `mypassword` to unlock it. Is there something I am doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Check your version of PHP and libzip. According to the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.setpassword#refsect1-ziparchive.setpassword-notes), `setPassword()` is only used for decryption in earlier version.

Comment: I have PHP 7.3. The function seems to work, partially at least, except the password is not recognized when trying to unzipping. It can zip with a password but cannot be unzipped. Kinda like the Seinfeld taking vs holding of the reservation lol.

Comment: PHP 7.3 and Libzip 1.8

Comment: Your code is fine. The problem is that you cannot open your password protected file with Windows inbuilt zip extraction function. You have to install 7-Zip for exampla to be able to extract it on Windows.